# Spring JPA with boolean fields throws "cannot resolve property exception"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am facing, "could not resolve property isManager of" Hibernate query exception.

I have the following java class:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "employee_id")
private Integer employeeId;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "is_manager")
private boolean manager;

public Integer getEmployeeId() {
   return employeeId;
}

public void setEmployeeId(Integer employeeId) {
   this.employeeId = employeeId;
}

public String getName(){
   return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
   this.name = name;
}

public boolean isManager(){
   return employeeId;
}

public void setManager(boolean manager) {
   this.manager = manager;
}
```

These are the eclipse generated setters and getters. When I replaced,

```
public boolean isManager() {
   return employeeId;
} with

public boolean getManager() {
   return employeeId;
}
```

The error is gone. I have gone through so many stack overflow examples. But everywhere, it's given, we shouldn't name the field that starts with "is".

Could anyone please explain?

Thanks.

Comment: please use the BOOLEAN class not the primitives because hibernate will try to save objects to database boolean is primitive

Comment: your code is perfectly fine as per the JPA spec (respecting java bean namings), so if Hibernate needs Boolean to be used then raise an issue on your JPA provider.

Comment: try to rename the getter to `getManager()`

Or you may rename the attribute to `isManager` --> the getter to  `getIsManager`

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate use the getXxx and setXxx for the all the variable . So the getter the **isManager** variable getter getManager() is not available  for hibernate.

so it get error.  To resolve the issue.

1. You can generate the your own getter and setter  as getManager() & setManager()
2. You can use the Boolean object instead of primitives.

Note: getIsManager is not meaningful to access the primitive boolean type. So Eclipse generate the getter for all the primitive start with isXXX as a getter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments.

I found the solution. When we name the field as isManager with the STS generated setter and getter, default value of Boolean, **false** is saved in DB.

field shouldn't start with auxiliary verb. According to my example:

```
 @Column(name = "is_manager")
 private boolean manager;

 public boolean isManager() {
    return employeeId;
 }

 public void setManager(boolean manager) {
    this.manager = manager;
 }
```

The above setter and getter works properly. I haven't updated the `@param` value in DB interface method.

Thanks.